# Need help setting up a sharedpreferences password screen on app start up

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

Ok, i tried to give it a small go on my own, but just ran into too many problems.

Can someone help me implement this? Or point me somewhere.  The bad news is I am looking for a complete instruction guide to this :/

I am implementing it into the google tabview tutorial, although i don't think it matters.

Thanks for help.  This should be a good reference for people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this tutorial here to setup shared preferences in my apps.

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Android/AndroidLiveWallpaper.aspx

To actually view how the settings are created, check the tutorial but download the source and review I remember there are bits missing from the tutorial about how to get it running.

Comment: does this tutorial explain how to setup a popup screen to allow users to register? or is this just for wallpaper?

Comment: The popup screen is the Shared Preferences Actvity, it's a separate activity that goes into your apk and is registered in your manifest. You can see it working from the sourcecode in the tutorial.  This is not just for live wallpapers.